# Postfix, procmailrc, SpamAssassin letting some but not all spam messages through

Tags: spam, spamassassin

I have postfix running on my server with a main.cf as follwos:-

```
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = 213.229.80.33, 127.0.0.1
mydestination = 213.229.80.33, corunna.com, localhost, corunnasystems.com
mynetworks = 213.229.80.33, 127.0.0.0/8

relay_domains =
home_mailbox = Maildir/

#  HELO restrictions

smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    permit

#  Sender restrictions

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    permit

#  Recipient restrictions

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   reject_unauth_pipelining,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
   permit_mynetworks,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
   reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
   check_policy_service unix:postgrey/socket,
   permit
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail
```

I have no /etc/procmailrc file but a .forward file

```
"|IFS=' ' && exec /usr/bin/procmail -f- || exit 75 #user"
```

on each of 2 logins on the server and also a .procmailrc file, also for each login.

```
:0
* ? echo $FROM | egrep -i -f /home/dconran/.whitelist
/var/mail/dconran

:0fw: spamassassin.lock
* < 64000
| spamassassin

:0:
* Subject:.*\[SPAM\]
megaspam

:0:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
megaspam

:0:
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*
bigspam
```

All of my messages are being piped through SpamAssassin (as far as I can tell) but some of them are then getting dumped in the megaspam and bigspam files but others with exactly the same SpamAssassin headers (ie showing that the message is spam) are getting through to my PC.

Why should some messages get through but seemingly exactly similar ones not get through?

Is there something wrong with my Postfix/.forward/.procmailrc setup?

Comment: Unless there is a piece missing from your `.procmailrc` there is nothing which sets `$FROM` and so the whitelisting check will never succeed.

Comment: Please update the question with a Procmail log excerpt.  Obtaining one is probably also sufficient for yourself to diagnose the actual problem.

Comment: The `user` comment is a placeholder which should be replaced with your actual account name; but unless you are running an antique Sendmail, this part of the `.forward` is completely unnecessary. In fact, most Postfix default configurations don't require any `.forward` at all, and will run Procmail if a `.procmailrc` file is detected.

Comment: point 1.  Sorry I copy & pasted only the bit that I thought was relevant (a. to keep it short and b. because bits of it are personal).  There is a FROM.  It is:  FROM=`formail -XFrom: -r -xTo: | tr -d ' '`.  Also NAME=`formail -xFrom: -c`  and  SUBJECT=`formail -xSubject: -c`

Comment: point 2.  I can't find any log anywhere nor is there an /etc/procmail file or any procmail.conf file that I can find.  What would it be called?

Comment: point3.  Sorry (again).  I do have my userid there, I just didn't want to publish it.

Comment: Thanks for helping on this.  It would seem from your second comment that, if there is no log file, is going to be helpful.  I'm not entirely sure how to set it up, as far as I can make out it is on a 'per procmail' basis and is setup using the command LOGFILE=/mydir/procmail.log.  Is that correct?  What baffles me is that (a) AFAIK it was working and (b) some emails are being filtered out but not others which have the same spam profile.

Comment: Yes, you need to set `LOGFILE` to a file you have write access to, and capture the log from one of these events which you want to troubleshoot. You should probably also set `VERBOSE=yes`, perhaps only selectively (inside the condition you want to debug?), perhaps with output to a separate log  file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm in the process of changing servers and will do as you suggest in the new set up.